# EXCEL How do I allow only part of a formula to be changed in a block?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have this formula in cell `A2`:

```
=A1*4+3
```

How do I lock `=A1*` and also lock "+3" so that when I type in cell `A2` it only changes the "4"?

For example, If I were to type "5" in cell `A2`; the formula would keep the `A1*` and "+3" but now change to:

```
=A1*5+3
```

Is that at all possible?

Comment: I think you would have to break this formula into two cells - one where you enter `3`, `5`, etc, and another with the rest of the formula. If you put a formula `=A1*B1+3` in cell A2, then enter `3` in cell B1, you get the result you want... almost. To make it so when you type a value into a cell it changes that into another value would require VBA.

Comment: No you can't mark partial values of a cell readonly. You will have to split the formula into multiple cells as the above commentator mentioned or use VBA to trigger resetting of cell value upon any change.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to have the background color of a cell change if that cell does not equal a certain value?

Comment: Yes, use conditional formatting.

Comment: This question does not belong on SO. Also, a "block" is called a cell. As someone who is just learning Excel, please post at Superuser.com instead.

Comment: I do believe I can use conditional formatting to accomplish what I am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I did not mean to misuse the site. I will check out superuser.com.

Answer (score 3):

the data entry cell will need to be different to the formula calculation cell otherwise you will get a circular reference, however you can set the reference to only reference a certain cell, certain column or certain row. by adding a $ to various parts of the reference.  So $A$1 would always reference cell A1. If you have $A1 then this is a fixed reference to Column A but a relative reference to Row 1. Similarly A$1 is a relative reference to Column A but a fixed reference to Row 1.  This is particularly useful when filling down or right and you want your formula to always reference particular group of cells

As for the background color changing depending of a certain value, have a look at conditional formatting.  failing that you can do it via VBA if necessary

Comment: I understand how fixed references work, but I don't believe this answer is all to relevant to my question. I don't wish to use multiple cells, just one. But I do believe I can use conditional formatting to accomplish what I want. Thank you. (I keep reading my comment and I feel like I sound rude. I hope you don't believe that I am trying to be rude at all.)

Comment: Cool, all good. :) I believe that you will have to separate out the Data Entry cell and the formula cell to get what you want though.  For the purposes of locking or protecting a cell, you can right click (context menu) format cell/protection. this will only work when the worksheet is protected though

Answer (score 3):

A "block" is called a cell.

If you want to use what you type in A2 in the calculation, then use A2 in the formula.

=A1*A2+3

Comment: A cell, got it! I understand I can use A2 in the formula and just place that formula in another cell. I am just trying to see if there is a way to further minimize the amount of cells needed by allowing just a partial change in the formula.